# why web service call is not working in all devices?

Tags: android, cordova

I am working on an android phone gap project. There is a login page, on click of the submit button a web service is called for authentication (using jqyey ajax. The issue is that when i run the project on emulator 4.2 It works fine, but when I run on a device 2.3, I am getting an error with status 403 (forbidden).

Comment: Providing code snippet is always a good idea.